# Php variables in <form action="

Tags: php, forms, variables

I don't know why i can't pass my variables to my php page in the form information.

Do you have any clues why my $_GET can't see the variables I'm sending.
I don't see the "record" variable and the "nb" variable also while i see my list of "firstname".
Cheers,
Here is the code :

```
    <form id='login' action='show-details.php?record=1&domain=<?Php echo $_GET['domain']; ?>&nb=<?Php echo $_GET['nb']; ?>' method='GET' accept-charset='UTF-8'>


        echo '<input type="text" name="txt_firstname'.$i.'" value="'.utf8_encode($row['first_name']).'"onblur="AutoTrim(this)" >' . "</h5>";
```

Comment: Why you write `<?Php` instead of `<?php`?

Comment: I guess it's the same thing... no?

Comment: And why `>' . "</h5>";` instead of `>Some Headline</h5>";`? Don't you have syntax highlightning?

Comment: why not just set those parameters as hidden inputs instead? you're already doing GET method with the form

Comment: I didn't put the whole code... Because it was too long... I just put the main first line which contains my question.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt Well, not to mention that's not even valid HTML - the opening tag is for `input` and is being closed by `h5`. Also, OP, in PHP double quotes, i.e, `"` would expand your variables, so something like `var $name = "MyName"; var $message = "They call me $name"` would work, so you don't have to do string concatenation. Also, there doesn't seem to be a space between the value of `value` and `onblur`.

Comment: Ohhh i works very well thanks a lot... Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

The php correct tag is not on uppercase: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php. The double quotes maybe is part of your problem:

```
<form id='login' action="show-details.php?record=1&domain=<?php echo $_GET['domain']; ?>&nb=<?php echo $_GET['nb']; ?>" method="GET" accept-charset="UTF-8">

 <?php
  echo '<input type="text" name="txt_firstname' . $i . '" value="'. utf8_encode($row['first_name']) . '" onblur="AutoTrim(this)" >';
  ?>
```